# How to call "raw mongo query" and retrieve strongly typed collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am looking for equivalent in `MongoDB` for this method known from `Entity Framework`:

```
public List<SomeDto> GetAll()
    {
        return _context
            .Database
            .SqlQuery<SomeDto>(@"SELECT id, name FROM Users")
            .ToList();
    }
```

I already have a mongo script which is working and is complex in some way:

```
db.getCollection('Some').aggregate(
[
  {
    $unwind: '$SocialData'
  },
  { 
    $match : { 
          "ServiceType" : 9
          } 
  },
  {
    $project : {
        mscore: { "$cond": [{ $eq: ["$SocialData.k", "mscore"]}, "$SocialData.v", null]},
        uscore: { "$cond": [{ $eq: ["$SocialData.k", "uscore"]}, "$SocialData.v", null]},
        scrappedDate : "$ScrappedDate",
        url: "$Url"
        }
  },
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { 
           url : "$url"
       },
       mscore: { "$max": "$mscore"},
       uscore: { "$max": "$uscore"},
       url: { "$first": "$url"},
       scrappedDate: { "$last": "$scrappedDate"},
    }
  },
  {
    $project : {
        id : "$_id.itemId",
        lastScrappedDate : "$scrappedDate",
        url : "$url",
        mscore: "$mscore",
        uscore: "$uscore",
        }
  },
  { 
      $sort : { 
          mscore: -1,
          uscore: -1,
          }
  }
]
)
```

I would like to if this is even possible and if yes how to achieve it or what is the best way to solve this task?